# Azure CLI choose a option from a table

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am trying to get a table output with numbers in the Azure CLI which gives this as a output

```
Number      Location     Name
----------  -----------  -------------
1           somewhere    ResourceGroup1
2           somewhere    ResourceGroup2
```

The code I have right now is

```
az group list --query '[].{location:location, name:name}'
```

The output I'm getting right now is

```
Location     Name
----------  ---------------
somewhere    ResourceGroup1
somewhere    ResourceGroup2
```

My end goal is that if you choose the number 1 you select the name so I can use that later in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `contains` expression (jmespath) in the filter to filter the results:

```
filter=resource_group_name
filterExpression="[?contains(name, '$filter')].name"
az group list --query "$filterExpression" -o tsv
```

which is a much better way compared to already present answers.

more reading:
http://jmespath.org/specification.html#filterexpressions
http://jmespath.org/specification.html#built-in-functions

Comment: I think i get what you are trying to do here but somehow i cant get this one working on my machine

Comment: just try azure cloud shell. this will only work on linux, not on windows. on windows you can use powershell

Comment: Unfortunatly i dont get any results back in the azure cloud shell

Comment: well, change the filter? change your working subscription?

Comment: i cant change the subscription and it seems like the filter terms isnt recognized at all

Comment: do you get any output from `az group list` in cloud shell? if you do - change the filter to match the name of one of the resource groups and it should work

Comment: This worked unfortunatly this isnt the anwser i was looking for

Comment: well, this is exactly what you are trying to do, filter the results

Comment: Hi, After rereading your answer and letting a colleague look at it i changed a few things and now it works and it is what i was searching for! the only thing i am trying to fix right now is that it is case sensitive

Comment: zthis is the code i am using right now
`az group list --query '[].{name:name}' --output table`
`$filter = Read-Host -Prompt "Please filter to find the correct resource group"`
`az group list --query "[?contains(name, '$filter')].name" --output table`

Comment: well, this was an example you are supposed to build upon :) best of luck

Answer (score 2):

For your issue, there is no Azure CLI command can achieve it. But you can use a script to let it come true. For example, you can use a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

az group list --query '[].{location: location, name: name}' -o table >> output.txt

# This command just add the line number inside the file, it's optional.
cat -n output.txt >> result.txt

# you can just get the group name with a specific line, the same result with output.txt
awk '{if (NR == line) print $3}' result.txt
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand you are trying to create variable to use later from output. You do not need to put it in a table first. Using same example you have you could do something like below;

`gpname="$(az group list --query [0].name --output tsv)"`

`az group show -n $gpname`

[image: Imgur]

Good Luck.....

**Information in Comments::**

What you are looking for is more Linux than Azure. I am not a Linux CLI expert but her is a basic script that you can build on.

`#!/bin/bash`

`gpnames="$(az group list --query [].name --output tsv)"`

`PS3='Select A number: '`

`select gpname in $gpnames`

`do`

`az group show -n $gpname`

`Done`

[image: Imgur]

Hope this helps......

Comment: I am indeed trying to make a variable from the resource group name but to do that you need to be able to select on first because in my case i will be working with loads of resource groups

Comment: What you are looking for is more Linux than Azure. I am not a Linux CLI expert but her is a basic script that you can build on.



`#!/bin/bash`


`gpnames="$(az group list --query [].name --output tsv)"`


`PS3='Select A number: '`


`select gpname in $gpnames`


`do`


`az group show -n $gpname`


`Done`


[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/mlUPZ4E.png)


Hope this helps......

Comment: This is indeed the output i need! Unfortunatly i dont avhe it working on my machine...yet. If this is indeed the solution i need ill send the powershell code and accept your anwser!